# Angular validation doesn't show first time message

Tags: javascript, angular, validation

Found something that little confusing, maybe because of my from form configuration, or some expression is missing in ngif for text error.
first time when I am typing the code inside field message doesn't show, when I click out from field and then click on field again message appears .
By first time I mean, first clicking and typing in a field after page reloads.

[image]
[image]

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-product',
  templateUrl: './create-product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-product.component.scss']
})
export class CreateProductComponent implements OnInit{
  form = new FormGroup({
    title: new FormControl<string>('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(3),
    ])
  });

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  get title(){
    return this.form.controls.title as FormControl;
  }

  submit(){
    console.log(this.form.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- adding handler and form variable for  a form -->
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <!-- form control name - name of value in a form-->
    <input class='border w-full py-2 px-4 mb-2' type="text" placeholder="product name" formControlName="title"/><br />
    <button [disabled]="title.errors" class="py-2 px-4 bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold rounded" type='submit'>
        Add Product
    </button>
</form>

<p *ngIf="title.errors?.required && title.touched  && this.form.get('title')?.dirty" class="text-red-600 font-medium mx-2">Shouldn't be an empty</p>
<p *ngIf="title.errors?.['minlength'] && title.touched && this.form.get('title')?.dirty" class="text-red-600 font-medium mx-2">Too short, symbols-{{title.value.length}} (minimum 3 symb)</p>
```

Comment: why i think it is important, cause this message doesn't aper if click on button submit, only if out from form, because when i am clicking at button, field steal be active

Comment: See you wrote: `title.touched && && title.dirty`. You need understand when a formControl is touched and when is dirty. See an example in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ctfalh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html): dirty when change, touched when changeEnd

Comment: @Eliseo  , so maybe use or like if touched or already dirty